# Calculations to Determine Force Required for Gyroscopic Stabalization

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, stability, gyroscopes

I am currently undertaking a project involving gyroscopes, the aim of which is to stabilize a large object.

I have read that gyroscopes work because of conservation of angular momentum, and if you move a gyroscope (assuming it is mounted on near-frictionless gimbals*) it will move to keep the spin axis the same. I was hoping to apply this, by mounting a mass inside my object and spinning it with a motor.

When a gyroscope is forced to reposition, it exerts a force on the gimbals which turn easily because the friction between contact points is very small. If the contact points have more friction, (the gimbals need to be oiled, they are rusty, etc.) the gyroscope must exert more force to remain on the same spin axis.

Any force exerted on another object requires energy, and in this case, I would assume that since the gyroscope's moment of inertia cannot change, the energy must come out of the angular velocity.

If I have a gyroscope in a frame (one that only allows it to spin in one axis**) and try to change the axis of rotation, it will exert a force on me as a try to turn it. ***I would like to know how much force it exerts, based on the number of RPM the gyroscope is spinning.***
The amount by which the gyroscope slows is not of concern, because I can attach a motor to keep the number of RPM constant.

***I am looking for the equation, or set of calculations to determine this.*** Looking through several pages of Google searches for "Force exerted by tipped gyroscope" and other such searches have been fruitless.

From about 10 minutes of experimentation with a toy gyroscope I have observed that if you exert a force on a gyroscope, it does indeed lose angular velocity. However, worryingly, I have also observed that if you turn the frame and hold it, you can change the spin axis of the gyroscope. Would this be of concern with very high angular velocities? (several hundred RPM. I would spin my mass with a motor such as those found in model airplanes.)

*[Free floating gyroscope](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Gyroscope_operation.gif)

**[Fixed gyroscope](https://5bbbafd3-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/picturehostingsites/home/storage/Fixed%20gyro.png?attachauth=ANoY7co4FCaf4VaUHdjA__MAijJ3OIkJlbhw0IJYZTlu3WjTCZOpYG4ZQ08qUJ27_45mZO2BWWQj8zO0nhdLPIATLzyjJP9wLDBwfOYaE8saUjig6_W7qW0bOam6wi5d0h0Mw5m7oHQ2BnA2oH8D7cmITTrEC7esjREGJivQUFzkaOSIUWJgHyJOuunP_Kto-JXQtC-zVXHIeVnPgamfoxVa58PoVYHDPwBUhTPjGfY6nZjo091_KIgHSqYkSugf-QaOtRu5ZRLC&attredirects=0)

Comment: A gyroscope doesn't exert force but torque. The torque is perpendicular to the spin axis and the torque that tries to change the direction of the axis. As a result the gyroscope will go into a precession motion. The idea that a gyroscope will automatically stabilize its orientation against a disturbance is incorrect. It will merely show a complex dynamic response to such a disturbance. Practical gyroscopic stabilization requires an active mechanism, in which the gyroscopes (!) are merely the source of three stable attitude vectors. They must be isolated against torque by gimbals.

Comment: @CuriousOne So I cannot attach a rotating mass to a free-floating object, and expect the object to retain stability along the spin axis of the rotating mass? (assuming the mass is rotating sufficiently quickly)

Comment: @CuriousOne In the setup I planned to use, a mass was spun by a motor so the spin axis was perfectly vertical. The object would be then released and hopefully the gyroscope would keep the object vertical while it was free-floating. In an idealized world without external forces beyond my control, I doubt I would need stabilization. However since this is not an ideal world, I assumed I would need a stabilizer of some sort.

Comment: Depending on the setup and the external torque on the gyroscope the best you can expect is a slow precession. In the worst case you will get chaotic tumbling. That's the best a passive gyroscope can do for you. If you want better than that, you need an active stabilization mechanism. I any case, you are basically reinventing the wheel, quite literally. You can buy electronic gyroscopic stabilizers for RC models for maybe a couple hundred dollars.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm trying to do this on the cheap. I do a random project every month or two, and I thought this might be interesting. What about a system of gyroscopes arranged on 3 of the 4 sides of a tetrahedron, with the point down? Could that work?

Comment: Cheap is a relative term. To me a multi-million dollar gyroscope to stabilize a multi-billion dollar spacecraft is cheap. To answer your physics question: increasing the number of rotating masses will not help. You are actually more likely to build an outrageously chaotic system. The most stable you can get is probably a flat rotating disk, which, as I said, will give you a fairly easy to understand precession movement. I gave you the one and only recipe to gyroscopic stabilization: the gyroscope is mounted inside a gimbal and it is kept as torque free as can be.

Comment: @CuriousOne To be slightly more specific, I am attempting to build a micro set of [reaction wheels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wheel). If I mount one one each axis, then it should work. (assuming I can find the correct programming for a microcontroller.) I am trying to find the relevant equations but so far, not much luck. I think I need to come up with a better Google search than what I was trying.

Comment: @CuriousOne That is, I changed my setup idea from a momentum wheel* to a set of reaction wheels. *[about 1/2 of the way down the page.](http://www.reactionwheel.com/resources/reactionwheel.html)

Comment: Reaction wheels are not gyroscopes. The gyroscope is your attitude sensor, the reaction wheels are the actuators. Reaction wheels only make sense in space because they will almost instantaneously saturate in a terrestrial scenario where the external torque is neither small nor limited in duration. The relevant equation for all of this can be found easily on the internet under "moments of inertia", but I am afraid that what you think of as a weekend project has some serious degrees of difficulty that are beyond what you will want to deal with.